# Why does my vba code keep freezing?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

So i just want to open word documents and then get their values but it doesnt seem t0 work and keeps freezing my excel.

Doest anybody know what i have to do?
Im trying to loop trough a directory of files and then open each one and do things with it

```
    Public i As Long

Sub loopDir()

Dim file As Variant

   directory = "D:\Exceloplossing\ZRM\"
   file = Dir(directory & "*.docx")
   Do While (file <> "")
      Call transfer(directory & file)
     file = Dir
Loop
End Sub

Sub transfer(file As String)

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsZRM As Worksheet
    Dim wsZRMSCORE As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsZRM = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set wsZRMSCORE = wb.Sheets(2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(file, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False, ReadOnly:=False)
    'Debug.Print objDoc.FormFields(91).Result
    On Error GoTo Ending






    'ZRM invullen
   Row = lastRowInUse("A")
    'ZRM ID = BESTANDSNAAM:
    wsZRM.Cells(Row, 1) = filename
    'KLANT_ID = BSN:
    wsZRM.Cells(Row, 2) = "d"
    'SAVEDATE = DATUM_ZRM:
    wsZRM.Cells(Row, 3) = "d"




    objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing: Set objWord = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Ending:
objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing: Set objWord = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
Function lastRowInUse(col As String) As Long

        Dim lastRow As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, col).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        lastRowInUse = lastRow + 1

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a `Stop` statement somewhere and just stepping through the code? Also, if you think your code is stuck in an infinite loop, you can try either (a) pressing Ctrl + Break or (b) holding Alt + Escape until it breaks. That's how I get out of those most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of reasons might be there. Here are the two most obvious:

**Reason 1**:
You do not have `Option Explicit` on top and your code does not compile. Write it, compile it and check every problem.

**Reason 2**: 
You have forgotten to write `Exit Sub` before `Ending:` here:

```
  objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing: Set objWord = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Ending:
    objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing: Set objWord = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thus your code goes through `Ending:` again. And it cannot close what is still closed. Thus, you get an error (but not an endless loop, as I thought initially). This is a possible way to go around it:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On error goto 0
    Exit sub

Ending:
    on error resume next
    objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing: Set objWord = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    on error goto 0
End Sub
```

Comment: If an error forces the code to go to `Ending` (which, as you point out will happen because `objDoc` has been set to `Nothing`) then the next time it tries to execute `objDoc.Close` it will throw an error message (because it is within the error handler the second time around) - it shouldn't be causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @YowE3K - true, VBE was better than I thought.

Comment: So ... zero infinite loops :D  (I wonder whether the error message from the second time through the `Ending` was being "hidden" for some reason - that might make it look as if it was "frozen" - I don't have time to experiment and see if I can replicate it though.)

Comment: @YowE3K - replication would be time consuming, the code does not compile and you need to rewrite it a bit.

Comment: I was just about to ask about that - it seemed to compile OK on my computer.  Which bit failed for you?

Comment: Adding `Option Explicit`. `Directory` was not defined. Did not got further.

Comment: OK - so the OP's code compiles, but with some variables defaulting to `Variant` though.  I thought I was missing something.  (Thought I was going crazy.  Or crazier.)

Comment: @YowE3K - I don't know, for me it does not compile. What is `filename`? Procedure or a missed variable?

Comment: `filename` will default to a `Variant` variable.

Comment: @YowE3K - or it can be some function, bringing some value to `wsZRM.Cells(Row, 1)`?

Comment: Yes, `filename` could be a function ... if **explicitly** defined as such.  But it defaults to a `Variant/Empty` variable if not explicitly defined.

Comment: @YowE3K - looking at the code of the guy, it looks like it is a function, or he missed assigning value to it and defining it. Anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty obvious to me:

```
file = Dir(directory & "*.docx")
Do While (file <> "")
   Call transfer(directory & file)
   file = Dir
Loop
```

Unless I'm missing something, `Dir` never gets set to anything else so your loop is going to run forever.

Think you want `file = Dir()`

Comment: 2 independent endless loops in 73 lines. That's fun.

Comment: @Vityata consistency is key.

Comment: Nope, `Dir` without parameters will call [`FindNextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx), assuming that a previous call to `Dir` with parameters resulted in a successful [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx). VBA doesn't care if you call it like a statement or a function. *It just works™* ... shrug ...

Comment: @rene fair enough, my VB is pretty rusty, just going off the example in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4a2w9xx(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). To be fair, `Dir()` signals intent too, `Dir` stood out like a sore thumb to me but that's a criticism on the language and not the developer :)

Comment: I admit while typing the comment I tested the code to make sure my own rusty-ness  wouldn't bite back ... cheers!